# What is the planned Nuwa city atmosphere?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, colonization, pressure

[Nuwa](https://spacearchitect.org/portfolio-item/nuwa-martian-city/) is a proposal for a large-scale permanent Martian settlement.

What is the planned atmospheric composition of Nuwa city's air? Will it be 15psi Oxygen/nitrogen, and trace gases or low partial pressure oxygen.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Nuwa Concept Technical Report](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349870316_The_Nuwa_Concept_A_development_model_for_a_self-sustainable_city_on_Mars), the habitat atmosphere will be 30% oxygen by volume at 75kPa (~11 psi), with the balance being nitrogen, argon, and CO2. Agricultural modules will be kept at lower pressure with a CO2-rich mix.

Comment: "An inert gas (a combination of nitrogen or argon) will also be present in the atmosphere to ensure oxygen levels are kept within safe limits."  It seems like they haven't decided if it will be one or the other or both. Agricultural modules might want nitrogen for those plants that like to do nitrogen fixation. Luckily N2 and Ar are ≥2% components of Mars' atmosphere already.